# iOS App Version Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, build, version-control, app-store-connect

I have update already live app and change bundle short version string from **1.3.1** to **1.3.2**.

In code, i am using this code to get version and display current version in profile view.

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
```

This will give me **1.3.2** when i am running app through Xcode.

Up to this all things are good.

Now i create app in iTunes with version **1.4** and upload version **1.3.2** into it. And apple approve this build and live the app.

So, in live app which version will display in profile view with above code (Either **1.4** or **1.3.2**)?

Thank You. :)

Comment: I think 1.3.2 will appear in your profile view.

Answer (score 0):

It will show 1.3.2 since you are referring from bundle infoDictionary which have value of 1.3.2. and not from the iTunes version.

But I yet have question, did apple really accept your version 1.3.2 and its it live, because it may even fail to validate since the versions will not match.